# MergeSort and QuickSort swaps questions

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort, mergesort

In quickSort, given an array `a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` when I count swaps, it always returns `5` when it's sorted. How is that? I thought that swaps should be counted only when it actually swaps two numbers. 
Another example - given an array `a[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5};` it returns `swaps = 4`. I don't really understand how they work.

```
int swapsQuick = 0;

int partition(int *L, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = left;
    int p_val = L[pivot];

    while (left < right) {
        while (L[left] <= p_val)
            left++;
        while (L[right] > p_val)
            right--;
        if (left < right) {
            swap(&L[left], &L[right]);
            swapsQuick++;
        }
    }
    swap(&L[pivot], &L[right]);
    swapsQuick++;
    return right;
}

int quicksort(int *L, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end)
        return swapsQuick;
    int splitPoint = partition(L, start, end);
    quicksort(L, start, splitPoint - 1);
    quicksort(L, splitPoint + 1, end);
    return swapsQuick;
}
```

Also, which part of this `mergeSort` help function actually swaps two numbers?

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];

    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is not returning the number of swaps. Where is it from?

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't put the counter in this function because I don't know where to put it. I don't understand which part of the code actually swaps two integers.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking where the count comes from. You are asking why it always gives `5` but you don't show where that comes from. So nobody can answer.

Comment: The merge function doesn't do swaps.  It moves values around, but does not perform pairwise swaps.  It copies the two sorted halves of the array into `L` and `R`, then compares the first value of each, placing the smallest one back in the original array, repeatedly until the array is full.  There are no pairwise swaps.

Comment: @me995 And where is there  quickSort ?

Comment: Oh, sorry everyone, I accidentally didn't copy code for quickSort. I edited the post with code.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's what's confusing me. Instructor said to modify the code so it returns number of swaps, pairwise. I really don't understand how's that possible.

Comment: @me995 Ask your instructor to give an example.  If the input is `2, 3, 1` and the output is `1, 2, 3`, how many pairwise swaps is that?  The point is there in no place in `merge` where it is swapping a single pair of values.  Just tell your instructor that it does not perform pairwise swaps.  Perhaps he/she was checking to see who would realize that?

Comment: @TomKarzes I will ask him that. Maybe he thought about parts where two numbers get compared and rotated. I don't know what he thought. We have to modify quick and merge sort to return number of swaps, and compare which one returns smaller number.

Comment: Keep in mind that the swaps are only part of the complexity.  If you really want a good comparison, you need to count the number of compares as well (which is much better defined than the number of swaps).  In fact, that's what this assignment *should* have asked you to count.  It could also have asked you to count the number of time values are *moved*.  Perhaps that's what the intent was?  It's not the same as pairwise swaps.

Comment: @TomKarzes maybe that's the intention. He just said "return the number of completed changes (where change is swap of two variables)".

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know exactly what he wanted.  Send him an email asking for clarification.

Comment: @TomKarzes do you have a comment on quickSort? Is there a problem with swaps there?

Comment: Quicksort is a bit clearer.  Your version actually calls a `swap` function to perform a pairwise swap, so you can just count the number of calls to that function.  But that's because all data movement in quicksort is in the form of pairwise swaps.  Your `swapsQuick` counter should work for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `partition` function that may explain the incorrect count:

- the loop `while (L[left] <= p_val) left++;` may go beyond the end of the array if the pivot chosen is the smallest element of the slice, which is always the case for a sorted slice. You should change it to:

  ```
  while (left <= right && L[left] <= p_val)
      left++;
  ```

Comment: I still get the same. For a sorted array, it just returns number of elements in the array.